# Как задать разрешение на видео сигнал с камеры?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, capture, videocapture

Помогите пожалуйста, программа делает скриншоты, но разрешение камеры 1920x1080, а выходное разрешение на файле 640x480. Мне нужно чтобы на выходе было изображение с максимальным разрешением.

не смог найти адекватного решения в интернете

```
using DirectShowLib;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.Util;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;

namespace Vision
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private VideoCapture capture = null;
        private DsDevice[] webCams = null;
        private int selectedCameraId;
        private readonly string TemplateFileName = @"D:\BASE\Shablon osmotra.docx";

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        //загрузка формы
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webCams = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            for (int i = 0; i < webCams.Length; i++)
            {
                toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(webCams[i].Name);
            }
        }        
        private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedCameraId = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }    

        private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.None).Bitmap;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (webCams.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Нет доступных камер!");
                }
                else if (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Необходимо выбрать камеру!");
                }
                else if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    capture = new VideoCapture(selectedCameraId);
                    capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
                    capture.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btn_scrennshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\BASE\Images"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\BASE\Images");
                    MessageBox.Show("Папка для снимков создана");
                }
                else
                {
                    string path = @"D:\BASE\Images";
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(path + @"\" + textBox_surename.Text + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }

                var panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
                panel.AutoSize = true;
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);

                //параметры скриншота
                var pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Image = new Bitmap (m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.None).Bitmap);                
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pb.Name = $"SMV_{textBox_surename.Text + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second}";
                pb.Height = pb.Image.Height / 3;
                pb.Width = pb.Image.Width / 3;

                //имя
                var name = new Label();
                name.Text = $"SMV_{textBox_surename.Text + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: странное совпадение - `pb.Height = pb.Image.Height / 3;`  .... 1920/3 = 640.

Comment: действительно странное совпадение 640 - это значение по умолчанию, /3 - это размер динамически создаваемого изображения в flowLayotPanel, и эти данные никак не связаны с разрешением получаемого видео сигнала с камеры, они задают параметры передаваемого изображение в динамически создаваемый picturebox.

Comment: вообще это ты задаешь вручную высоту твоего пикчеПанела. То есть формальо ты выставляешь ему высоту 640 пикселей. Как именно на 640 пикселях может отобразиться изображение больше 640 пикселей? А вообще гугл подсказывает что у твоего capture можно задать FrameWidth и  FrameHeight

Comment: @Andrew в ответе решение написал если интересно, подсказали добрые люди, проверил, работает

Comment: ты не поверишь, но я подсказал ровно то же самое решение)

Comment: @Andrew спасибо, но к сожалению я знаком с c# недели 3-4, поэтому для меня решение в виде конкретных строк кода намного более понятное к восприятию как "решение".

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение этого вопроса

Нужно вызвать метод с нужными параметрами размера...

```
capture = new VideoCapture();
capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameHeight, 1080);
capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameWidth, 1920);
capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Fps, 60);
```

Спасибо доброму человеку(Someone007), за решение.